# When referring to a specific war (or other named event), should the word "war" be capitalized when it appears alone?

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns

> The Cold War instilled a fear of nuclear war in the public; additionally, the [war] was responsible for an extreme anti-Communist sentiment that lingers to this day.

Should the bracketed instance of "war" be capitalized? *Can* it be capitalized, possibly as an abbreviation of the war's full name?

Comment: [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+war+was%2C+the+War+was&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows that the general rule is **not** to capitalize "war", except if you are talking about the Great War, and are writing between 1920 and 1939, in which case you may capitalize "War" if you so desire. Compare [the Depression](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+depression+was%2Cthe+Depression+was&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I generally would not capitalize it. A similar case would be the following sentence:

> The Red Sox play at Fenway Park. Located in Boston, the park is the oldest in Major League Baseball.

where the second "park" is not capitalized.

I think you *might* be able to capitalize it as an abbreviation of the war's full name, but I wouldn't recommend it unless you make it clear that it is a shortening of the war's full name and you plan to continue using it throughout the rest of the (dialogue/paper/article).

Answer (score 6):

My own preference would be to leave it as it is, since 'war' on its own is not a proper noun, even if it refers to something that is.